# Matching value to class attribute in python

Tags: python, attributes

So I'm trying to complete a simple memory game as a final project, but I've run into some trouble searching through my cards and matching them to a value th user inputs.
What the code looks like now is this:

```
import random
from Graphics import *

class Card(object):
"""A card object"""

WIDTH = 25
HEIGHT = 25

    def __init__(self, x, y, n):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.n = n
        p = ((x + (Card.WIDTH/2)),(y + (Card.HEIGHT/2)))

        """Creates a card with the given value and suit."""
        self.value = random.random
        self.color = 0
        self.face = 0
        self.appearance = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x + Card.WIDTH, y + Card.HEIGHT))
        self.appearance.setOutline(Color(255, 255, 255))
        self.appearance.setFill(Color(142, 142, 142))
        self.appearance.setWidth(2)
        self.appearance.draw(win)
        self.text = Text(p, str(n))
        self.text.setFontSize(12)
        self.text.draw(win)


    def showFace(self):
        '''flips the card over'''
        self.face = 1
        ran = self.value
        if ran > 0 and ran < .20:
             self.appearance.setFill(Color("red"))
             self.color = 3
        if ran > .20 and ran < .40:
            self.appearance.setFill(Color("blue"))
            self.color = 4
        if ran > .40 and ran < .60:
            self.appearance.setFill(Color("green"))
            self.color = 5
        if ran > .60 and ran < .80:
            self.appearance.setFill(color("yellow"))
            self.color = 6
        if ran > .80 and ran < .100:
            self.appearance.setFill(color("purple"))
            self.color = 7

    def unShowFace(self):
        '''flips card back'''
        self.face = 0
        self.appearance.setFill(Color(142, 142, 142))

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        rows = 10
        columns = 10
        x = 100
        y = 125
        n = 1
        for j in range(10):
            for k in range(10):
                x = x+25
                c = Card(x, y, n)
                self.cards.append(c)
                n = n + 1
            y = y+25
            x = 100

win = Window("Memory Game", 500, 500)
win.setBackground(Color(64, 64, 64))

# Game title
title = Text(Point(win.getWidth()//2, 60), "Memory Mania")
title.setFill(Color(95, 115 ,200))
title.fontSize = 40
title.draw(win)

class Game():
    '''Runs the memory game'''
    def play(self):
        '''starts the game'''
        self.deck = Deck()

        matches = 0
        #While the game is not finished
        while True:
            while True: #The First Card
                card1 = input("Enter number of first card")
                for card in self.deck.cards:
                    if card.n == card1:
                        guess1 = card
                        guess1.showFace()
                break
            while True: # The Second Card
                card2 = input("Enter number of second card")
                for card in self.deck.cards:
                    if card.n == card2:
                        guess2 = card
                        guess2.showFace()
                break
            if guess1.color == guess2.color:
                matches = matches + 1
                if matches == 50:
                    break
            else:
                print('Not an identical pair.')
                guess1.unShowFace()
                guess2.unShowFace()

def main():
    game = Game()
    game.play()

main()
```

When I run the code, however, and input values for the first and second card, I get an error saying "UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'guess1' referenced before assignment." Is there a way I'm not seeing to check the attributes of the cards like I'm trying to?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
guess1 = card
```

is not guaranteed to be executed. `self.deck.cards` could be empty or `card.n == card1` could never be true.

In that case,

```
guess1.color == guess2.color
```

throws an error because `guess1` is not defined.

(`guess2` has the same problem.)

edit: upon further examination, I am pretty sure that the problem is that

```
input("Enter number of first card")
```

returns a string because you are using Python 3, but `card.n` is an integer, so `card.n == card` can never be true.

Use

```
card1 = int(input("Enter number of first card"))
```

and do the same for `card2`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My thought was in stating self.deck = Deck the list I created there would carry over. Is this not true? I know if the user inputs something other than an integer there will be a problem, I'm planning on adding checks for that soon, but now when I input just a number, I get the same error